# Chord DHT Graph with D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to display a visualize a Chord like DHT in D3JS, currently I've nodes being rendered correctly as seen in Image 1, only missing the arrows between nodes representing the fingers.

[image: Image 1 - DHT Visualizer]

This is my what I've managed to figure so far, but the arcs are nos displayed correctly
https://github.com/diasdavid/webrtc-explorer-visualizer/blob/master/src/client/app/index.js#L125-L140

The full code can be found here:
https://github.com/diasdavid/webrtc-explorer-visualizer

Run with `npm i && npm start`

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my issue was that the drawing of the lines starts from where the node is located and not the offset of the canvas, it is working fine now:

[image]

thank you!